# fabs() does not work under modules

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have older application on the appStore. I wanted to update it for iOS 7, so I opened it under Xcode 5 and switched on objective-c modules under the Build Settings. Without that, compilation is pretty slow.

But this is causing problem with fabs() function, which I use in one makro defined in *-Prefix.pch file:

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON)
```

When I call this makro, it causes error thanks fabs() function:

*error: Called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer

warning: Implicit declaration of function '__tg_promote1' is invalid in C99

warning: Implicit declaration of function '__tg_fabs' is invalid in C99*

When I switch off the modules, everything works fine like before.

Any help? I am becoming desperate about this.
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933741/how-to-check-if-is-iphone-5-in-ios-7

Comment: I defined this macro in my project, just now and used it in some sample code. It works for me. Can you give some more info to reproduce the problem?? I'm on Mac OSX 10.9 and Xcode 5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- CGRect is { CGPoint, CGSize }. CGSize is { CGFloat, CGFloat }. CGFloat is a typedef for a float, not a double.
- `fabs` is declared to as `extern double fabs(double)`,

Change the #define to:

`#define IS_IPHONE_5 (fabsf( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( CGFloat )568.0 ) < FLT_EPSILON)`

Comment: It works!!! Thanks a lot! I have to look at these things more deeply. Thanks again!

Comment: Why not simply `568.0f` instead of the ugly `(CGFloat)568.0`?

Comment: I think that both should work. But for me it is interesting, that it was ok before and with modules, it just does not work. (And also the error message was not helpful - at least to me).